# In ruby rake db:migrate show the password failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using rails with postgresql which is on remote machine. I have edited database.yml file according to the requirement.but when i run rake db:migrate it shows password failure.. but the same password works with the psql command..
the error when i run rake db:migrate  is:

```
root@vdimc04 My_Postgres]# rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:141:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
** my database.yml file**


development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_pchamara
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
  password: password
  host: 192.168.1.101
  port: 5432
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_pchamara_test
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
  password: password


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_pchamara_production
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
  password: password
```

Comment: check your database credentials and settings in database.yml file in config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I got answer to my question...

When we start a new project with rails command like 'rails new demo' we have to include '--database=postgresql'. Then only the pg gem will gets to the bundle.. If it is not declared the pg gem will not comes to bundle..

And what i did in database.yml file is also correct. Everything is fine there...
When we use the  database of postgresql to rails, we have to make some modifications to pg_hba.conf that is located in the lib directory..

I made some modifications there at my ip to TRUST where before it is md5..

we Can use both TRUST and md5.

```
md5- requires a passowrd to connect to database
trust- not requires a password
```

thats it.. as ususal include password to database.yml file.
Now the server runs without any error...

**THANKS TO EVERYONE WHO HELPED ME TO FIGURE OUT THIS PROBLEM**